# Write PACE Report Query for Hotel Reservation data (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have reservation data (live snapshot) for a hotel in a Postgres database. I want to write a query that gives me a weekly PACE report so I can tell my manager how we are doing week over week.

This is how the data looks:

| input_date | arrival_date | cancel_date | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-26 | 2023-08-10 | 2023-08-05 | 1500 |
| 2023-07-27 | 2023-08-12 |  | 1200 |
| 2023-07-29 | 2023-08-15 |  | 1800 |
| 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-20 | 2023-08-12 | 2000 |
| 2023-08-05 | 2023-08-25 |  | 2400 |
| 2023-08-07 | 2023-08-30 | 2023-08-20 | 2600 |
| 2023-08-10 | 2023-09-02 |  | 3000 |
| 2023-08-12 | 2023-09-05 |  | 2800 |
| 2023-08-15 | 2023-09-08 |  | 2200 |
| 2023-08-18 | 2023-09-12 | 2023-09-05 | 1900 |
| 2023-08-20 | 2023-09-15 |  | 2100 |
| 2023-08-22 | 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-12 | 2300 |
| 2023-08-25 | 2023-09-20 |  | 2800 |
| 2023-08-28 | 2023-09-22 |  | 2900 |
| 2023-08-30 | 2023-09-25 | 2023-09-20 | 3100 |
| 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-28 |  | 2600 |
| 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-30 |  | 2700 |
| 2023-09-07 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-09-28 | 2900 |
| 2023-09-09 | 2023-10-05 |  | 2500 |
| 2023-09-12 | 2023-10-08 | 2023-10-02 | 2300 |

```
input_date = the date of reservation
arrival_date = the date of start of reservation
cancel_date = the date when the reservation was cancelled
revenue = the revenue from the reservation (before cancellation)
```

Constraints - Our year starts in April, and the weeks start on Wednesdays

I want to be able to see for a particular week, say w.c. 2023-08-06 (from input_date), what do my revenues look like for each month of arrival_date.

For historical data to 2023-08-06, we calculate how much revenue I made except cancellations in each month of arrival_date.

For future months of arrival date to 2023-08-06, I want to look at how much revenue did I have on the books as of 2023-08-06. So we need to remove cancellations that happen after 2023-08-06 from this part.

Similarly for the w.c. 2023-08-13, how do my historical revenues look like for each month of arrival_date (after cancellations), and how do my revenue on the books (not taking cancellations into account) look for future months of arrival_date.

What I have is the latest snapshot of data here. What I'm trying to create with this PACE report is the ability to see how the snapshot looked for each week of input_date in the past. I appreciate that this might have to be broken down in to various queries. I'm not able to understand how to go about solving this and create that historical snapshots effect.

Comment: Not everyone knows what a "PACE report" is - I didn't. Apparently it is: **1** commonly used in the hotel industry to track and analyze various metrics related to revenue, reservations, business mix, and other factors **2**may include information on reservation activities, such as the number of bookings, cancellations, and modifications **3** may also provide insights into the business mix, which refers to the distribution of revenue from different sources, such as room types, packages, or customer segments

Comment: *"Our year starts in April, and the weeks start on Wednesdays"*  so your 2023 started on Wed 5th April (is that correct?) - what do you do with the day or days that are "left over". Do you have a "calendar table" of any sort (if so detail of this please). Does **w.c.** mean "week commencing"?

Comment: 2023 started on 1st April with a short week, 5th April 2023 is the start of the second week. w.c. does mean week commencing.

Comment: Does it help to create a "calendar table" manually and then use it for lookups for the pace query?

Comment: A calendar table can certainly help, depends on how often you need such a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example approach that uses a "calendar table" - a lot of this is assumed and please note that you can also store other items of information in such a table (e.g. holiday names that may influenece price/reservations etc.)

```
CREATE TABLE fiscal_calendar (
      date_val DATE
    , fiscal_year INTEGER
    , fiscal_week INTEGER
    , fiscal_month INTEGER
    );
```

A sample script to generate some basic rows in such a table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_fiscal_calendar (
    start_year INTEGER
)
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    loop_date DATE;
    end_date DATE;
    fiscal_year INTEGER;
    fiscal_week INTEGER;
    fiscal_month INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Start from April 1 of the start_year
    loop_date := (start_year || '-04-01')::DATE;
    end_date := (start_year + 1 || '-03-31')::DATE;

    WHILE loop_date <= end_date  LOOP
        fiscal_year := EXTRACT(YEAR FROM loop_date);

        -- Determine the fiscal month
        IF EXTRACT(MONTH FROM loop_date) > 3 THEN
            fiscal_month := EXTRACT(MONTH FROM loop_date) - 3;
        ELSE
            fiscal_month := EXTRACT(MONTH FROM loop_date) + 9;
        END IF;  

        -- Determine the fiscal week (starting on April 1)
        fiscal_week := EXTRACT(WEEK FROM loop_date - INTERVAL '2 day') - EXTRACT(WEEK FROM (fiscal_year || '-04-01')::DATE) + 1;

        -- Adjust negative week numbers for the previous fiscal year
        IF fiscal_week < 1 THEN
            fiscal_week := fiscal_week + EXTRACT(WEEK FROM (fiscal_year - 1 || '-12-31')::DATE);
        END IF;

        IF loop_date = (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM loop_date) || '-04-01')::DATE THEN
            fiscal_week := 1;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO fiscal_calendar (
            date_val,
            fiscal_year,
            fiscal_week,
            fiscal_month
        )
        VALUES (
            loop_date,
            fiscal_year,
            fiscal_week,
            fiscal_month
        );

        -- Move to the next day
        loop_date := loop_date + INTERVAL '1 day';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Calling that procedure:

```
select generate_fiscal_calendar(2023)
```

Example of the calendar's data:

```
select 
      * 
    , extract(dow from date_val) as dow
    , case extract(dow from date_val)
        when 0 then 'Sun'
        when 1 then 'Mon'
        when 2 then 'Tue'
        when 3 then 'Wed'
        when 4 then 'Thu'
        when 5 then 'Fri'
        when 6 then 'Sat'
    end as weekday
from fiscal_calendar
where fiscal_week < 3
```

| date_val | fiscal_year | fiscal_week | fiscal_month | dow | weekday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023 | 1 | 1 | 6 | Sat |
| 2023-04-02 | 2023 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Sun |
| 2023-04-03 | 2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Mon |
| 2023-04-04 | 2023 | 1 | 1 | 2 | Tue |
| 2023-04-05 | 2023 | 2 | 1 | 3 | Wed |
| 2023-04-06 | 2023 | 2 | 1 | 4 | Thu |
| 2023-04-07 | 2023 | 2 | 1 | 5 | Fri |
| 2023-04-08 | 2023 | 2 | 1 | 6 | Sat |
| 2023-04-09 | 2023 | 2 | 1 | 0 | Sun |
| 2023-04-10 | 2023 | 2 | 1 | 1 | Mon |
| 2023-04-11 | 2023 | 2 | 1 | 2 | Tue |

An example of weekly aggregations using the calendar table:

```
select
    a.fiscal_week
  , min(a.date_val) as wc
  , sum(r.revenue) as booked_revenue
  , sum(case when r.cancel_date is NOT null then r.revenue else 0.0 end) as canceled_revenue
  , sum(case when r.cancel_date is null then r.revenue else 0.0 end) as net_revenue
from reservations r
inner join fiscal_calendar a on r.arrival_date = a.date_val
left join fiscal_calendar c on r.cancel_date = c.date_val
group by
    a.fiscal_week
order by
    min(a.date_val)
```

| fiscal_week | wc | booked_revenue | canceled_revenue | net_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 2023-08-10 | 4500.0000 | 1500.0000 | 3000.0000 |
| 21 | 2023-08-20 | 2000.0000 | 2000.0000 | 0.0 |
| 22 | 2023-08-25 | 2400.0000 | 0.0 | 2400.0000 |
| 23 | 2023-08-30 | 8400.0000 | 2600.0000 | 5800.0000 |
| 24 | 2023-09-08 | 4100.0000 | 1900.0000 | 2200.0000 |
| 25 | 2023-09-15 | 4400.0000 | 2300.0000 | 2100.0000 |
| 26 | 2023-09-20 | 8800.0000 | 3100.0000 | 5700.0000 |
| 27 | 2023-09-28 | 8200.0000 | 2900.0000 | 5300.0000 |
| 28 | 2023-10-05 | 4800.0000 | 2300.0000 | 2500.0000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eYc8JdHm)

Comment: Great stuff. I've created the fiscal year calendar table and inserted dates from year 2018 to 2030.

Comment: So for calculating the revenue (for a particular arrival month), I've figured out that the condition should be:

Cancel Date > Start of Week of the Input Date // Don't remove future cancellations 

OR

ISNULL([Cancel Date]) // Remove past cancellations

Comment: So, you are now on the road to solving the overall problem? Hope so.

Comment: Still struggling to write the query that does the calculation @Paul Maxwell

Comment: Write out the business logic in business terms. Don't try jumping to the technical until you have the logic fully described.

Comment: Here's the Business Logic:

For each week of input date, I want to calculate the revenue for each month of arrival date, up to that input date.

I want the output table to have month of arrival date in the column and week of input date in the rows. Revenue as of that input week in the cells.

The cancel date can be after this week of input_date because, at that point in time, those cancellations had not taken place.

OR

The cancel date has to be empty, thus removing canceled bookings from the past of that input date week.

Comment: Can you help with that? @Paul Maxwell

Comment: There also seems to be an issue with the fiscal week logic. The logic break near 2019-01-01, it shows the fiscal year as 2019, when it should be 2018. Fiscal weeks after that date are negative, which should not be the case.

Comment: Sorry I did not intend that script to be the solution and it want extensively tested. Just an example. To be honest you may be better off generating the data you need using a spreadsheet and inserting that.

Comment: I was merely attempting to show how a calendar table can assist. Regarding ongoing further assistance: the site works best if you ask very specific questions demonstrating that you aren't able you solve that problem it yourself.